# Use Criteria to select a particular field from DB?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a method like below

```
public List<String> getSimilarResourceNames(String resourceName){
    String searchString = "%"+resourceName+"%";
    Session session = getSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Resource.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("name", searchString));
    return  criteria.list()
}
```

This will return me the entire resource from the DB, but what i need is just the name of the resource. How can I accomplish that ?

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Projection`, you can find examples in [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection).

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Resource.class);
criteria.setProjection(Property.forName("name"))
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("name", searchString));
```

Answer (score 2):

By using [`Projection`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection) you will get other fields (Which you did not got by Projection) in your `Pojo` setted to default values. In [`HQL`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) you can get specified column values as follow:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select u.fullname from Users u");
List<Object[]> rows = query.list();
List<String> fullnames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Object[] row: rows) {
    fullnames.add(row[0]);
}
```

I hope this will help you.